# Silverlight MarkupExtension

Tags: silverlight, binding

I'm developing a map application in Silverlight. I have a type Polygon, containing the coordinates of a polygon together with a string containing the name of Brush resource loaded into the application. I'm binding this object directly to a template for drawing polygons. This template has a Fill-propery of type System.Windows.Media.Brush.

My goal is to let the xaml-parser do the lookup of the resource, considering I only have the name of the Brush and not the resource itself.

In Silverlight I want to achieve something similar to what Pedro Sampaio is showing in WPF in this blog post: http://www.e-pedro.com/2009/06/using-data-binding-with-static-resources-in-wpf/. He has created a BindableStaticResource inheriting the StaticResourceExtension-type. Then he can do the binding like this:

```
<Polygon Fill="{BindableStaticResource {Binding NameOfFillResource}}" />
```

Very elegant! But it appears that this is not an option in Silverlight since there are no MarkupExtension-type to subtype. I'm fairly new to Silverlight, and can't really think of a good, reusable way of implementing this.

Thanks!
HaraldV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are correct there is no way create your own markup extensions for silverlight.

I solve this sort of problem with a value converter.  I've answered this sort of thing so often I ended up blogging it [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx).

With the source for `StringToObjectConverter` in you project your can place an instance of the converter in your resources somewhere:-

```
        <local:StringToObjectConverter x:Key="StatusToBrush">
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="Overdue" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" x:Key="Urgent" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Silver" x:Key="__default__" /> 
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </local:StringToObjectConverter>
```

then your binding will look like:-

```
<Polygon Fill="{Binding NameOfFillResource, Converter={StaticResource StatusToBrush}}" />
```

Comment: FYI, Markup Extensions will be supported in Silverlight 5.

Comment: @Richard:  Are you giving a personal guarantee? ;) Features that make it even as a far as beta don't alwys make it into the final product.

Comment: True, but it was stated that features shown at the Silverlight Firestarter event were stable and only features they couldn't guarantee (or weren't ready) weren't shown. As Markup Extensions were listed as a feature at the event I'd say that's a fair guarantee. Scott Gu also mentioned ME's again on his .NET Rocks interview on SL5.

Comment: Thanks Anthony! I will use this approach until I get the real deal. :) Are there any way I can access named resources from the applications merged dictionary inside the converter instead of having a local dictionary wrapped inside the converter?

Comment: @HaraldV:  One approach would be to create a ResourceDictionary item and place the brushes in that. You can then use the `Source` property of the resource dictionary in the converter instead of listing all the brushes.  You can also use the `MergedDictionaries` property of a Resource dictionary in your app.xaml to reference the same xaml item.  That way you only define this set of brushes in one place.